# Adding actual date sequentially by iterating for each week

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

Below are the sample data.

```
structure(list(Starts = structure(c(18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 
18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 
18064, 18085, 18085, 18085, 18085, 18085, 18085, 18085), class = "Date"), 
    Ends = structure(c(18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 
    18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18091, 
    18091, 18091, 18091, 18091, 18091, 18091), class = "Date"), 
    Day = c("Mon on", "Tue on", "Wed on", "Thu on", "Fri on", 
    "Sat on", "Sun on", "Mon off", "Tue off", "Wed off", "Thu off", 
    "Fri off", "Sat off", "Sun off", "Mon on", "Tue on", "Wed on", 
    "Thu on", "Fri on", "Sat on", "Sun on")), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am trying to add the actual date sequentially for each row by iterating seven times (for one week) based on the start and end date (Weeks starts with Monday and ends with Sunday). The desired output is

```
structure(list(Starts = structure(c(18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 
18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 18064, 
18064, 18085, 18085, 18085, 18085, 18085, 18085, 18085), class = "Date"), 
    Ends = structure(c(18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 
    18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18070, 18091, 
    18091, 18091, 18091, 18091, 18091, 18091), class = "Date"), 
    Day = c("Mon on", "Tue on", "Wed on", "Thu on", "Fri on", 
    "Sat on", "Sun on", "Mon off", "Tue off", "Wed off", "Thu off", 
    "Fri off", "Sat off", "Sun off", "Mon on", "Tue on", "Wed on", 
    "Thu on", "Fri on", "Sat on", "Sun on"), `Actual Date` = structure(c(18064, 
    18065, 18066, 18067, 18068, 18069, 18070, 18064, 18065, 18066, 
    18067, 18068, 18069, 18070, 18085, 18086, 18087, 18088, 18089, 
    18090, 18091), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Based on the research, I understand that we can get the actual dates using the `seq`  function:

```
date = seq(as.Date("2019-06-17"), as.Date("2019-06-23"), by = "day")
```

However, finding difficult to iterate the day by 7 in the data frame. Appreciate your support.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the number of rows will always be divisible by 7 (per datum)?

Comment: Yes, I can see all the 7 days starting from Monday to Sunday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround would be this:

```
mydata %>%
  mutate(`Actual Date` = Starts + case_when(grepl("Mon", Day) ~ 0,
                                            grepl("Tue", Day) ~ 1,
                                            grepl("Wed", Day) ~ 2,
                                            grepl("Thu", Day) ~ 3,
                                            grepl("Fri", Day) ~ 4,
                                            grepl("Sat", Day) ~ 5,
                                            grepl("Sun", Day) ~ 6)) 


# A tibble: 21 x 4
   Starts     Ends       Day     `Actual Date`
   <date>     <date>     <chr>   <date>       
 1 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Mon on  2019-06-17   
 2 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Tue on  2019-06-18   
 3 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Wed on  2019-06-19   
 4 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Thu on  2019-06-20   
 5 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Fri on  2019-06-21   
 6 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Sat on  2019-06-22   
 7 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Sun on  2019-06-23   
 8 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Mon off 2019-06-17   
 9 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Tue off 2019-06-18   
10 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Wed off 2019-06-19
```

If you are sure that your data is in the correct order you can also group by `Starts` and do the following:

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(Starts) %>%
  mutate(`Actual Date` = Starts + 1:n() - 1)
```

Comment: Even though mine will get solved by the second option, the first option is all a nice workaround which can used as reference for anyone. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea via base R,

```
ddf$new <- unlist(lapply(split(ddf, ddf$Starts), function(i) {
              i1 <- seq(i$Starts[1], i$Ends[1], by = 'day'); 
              as.character(rep(i1, nrow(i) / 7))
              }))

ddf
#       Starts       Ends     Day        new
#1  2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Mon on 2019-06-17
#2  2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Tue on 2019-06-18
#3  2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Wed on 2019-06-19
#4  2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Thu on 2019-06-20
#5  2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Fri on 2019-06-21
#6  2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Sat on 2019-06-22
#7  2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Sun on 2019-06-23
#8  2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Mon off 2019-06-17
#9  2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Tue off 2019-06-18
#10 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Wed off 2019-06-19
#11 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Thu off 2019-06-20
#12 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Fri off 2019-06-21
#13 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Sat off 2019-06-22
#14 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Sun off 2019-06-23
#15 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Mon on 2019-07-08
#16 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Tue on 2019-07-09
#17 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Wed on 2019-07-10
#18 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Thu on 2019-07-11
#19 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Fri on 2019-07-12
#20 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Sat on 2019-07-13
#21 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Sun on 2019-07-14
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` package, you could solve it as follows:

```
setDT(dt1)
dt1[, `Actual Date` := .BY[[1]] + rep(0:6, .N/7), by = Starts]
#        Starts       Ends     Day Actual Date
#        <Date>     <Date>  <char>      <Date>    
# 1: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Mon on  2019-06-17
# 2: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Tue on  2019-06-18
# 3: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Wed on  2019-06-19
# 4: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Thu on  2019-06-20
# 5: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Fri on  2019-06-21
# 6: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Sat on  2019-06-22
# 7: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23  Sun on  2019-06-23
# 8: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Mon off  2019-06-17
# 9: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Tue off  2019-06-18
#10: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Wed off  2019-06-19
#11: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Thu off  2019-06-20
#12: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Fri off  2019-06-21
#13: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Sat off  2019-06-22
#14: 2019-06-17 2019-06-23 Sun off  2019-06-23
#15: 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Mon on  2019-07-08
#16: 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Tue on  2019-07-09
#17: 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Wed on  2019-07-10
#18: 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Thu on  2019-07-11
#19: 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Fri on  2019-07-12
#20: 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Sat on  2019-07-13
#21: 2019-07-08 2019-07-14  Sun on  2019-07-14
#        Starts       Ends     Day Actual Date
```